# applying a rolling error function using rollapply

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to calculate a rolling error function in R where I take the last 30 days and compute the rmse, move forward 1 day and take the last 30 days from this point and compute the new rmse.

My data looks like the following where I have a date and two values:

```
         dates         val1         val2
1   2010-01-01 -0.479526441 -0.294149127
2   2010-01-02 -0.860588950  0.426375720
3   2010-01-03 -0.660643894 -1.483020861
4   2010-01-04 -0.938748812 -1.631823690
```

Where am I going wrong in the code?

Data & attempt:

```
d <- data.frame(
  dates = seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2012-12-31"), by = 1),
  val1 = rnorm(1096),
  val2 = rnorm(1096)
)

d %>% 
  mutate(rollRMSE = rollapply(., width = 30, by = 1, FUN = Metrics::rmse(val1, val2)))
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'Metrics::rmse(val1, val2)' is not a function, character or symbol`

Comment: I think I can only apply the `rollapply` function over one column and not 2.

Comment: Yup. That's it...

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it now. I was trying to hack together a solution using the `rolling_origin` function but couldn't get it working: `d_rolled <- d %>% 
  rsample::rolling_origin(.,
                 initial = 30,
                 assess = 0,
                 cumulative = FALSE,
                 skip = 0)

x <- map(d_rolled$splits, ~analysis(.x)) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  summarise(rmse = Metrics::rmse(val1, val2))`

Comment: @user113156, @Soros,  `rollapply` has the `by.column=` argument which determines wherther it acts by column or over all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : setting `window` size as a variable

I have sliced the steps, rollapply will result in 29 less data with a 30 window so may want to collect this in another tibble.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

d <- data.frame(
        dates = seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2012-12-31"), by = 1),
        val1 = rnorm(1096),
        val2 = rnorm(1096)
)

rse <- function(x, y){sqrt((x-y)**2)}

# assign window size for moving average
window <- 30

d %>% tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
        mutate(err = rse(val1, val2),
             roll = c(zoo::rollapply(err, width = window, by = 1, FUN = mean), rep(NA, window -1) )
)
#> # A tibble: 1,096 x 5
#>    dates          val1   val2   err  roll
#>    <date>        <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2010-01-01 -0.0248   1.18  1.20   1.40
#>  2 2010-01-02 -0.684    0.603 1.29   1.38
#>  3 2010-01-03 -0.344   -1.92  1.58   1.42
#>  4 2010-01-04  0.447    0.319 0.128  1.38
#>  5 2010-01-05  0.123   -0.810 0.933  1.42
#>  6 2010-01-06  0.00384  2.29  2.29   1.43
#>  7 2010-01-07 -1.51    -1.03  0.487  1.39
#>  8 2010-01-08  0.394   -1.25  1.64   1.41
#>  9 2010-01-09 -1.30     1.61  2.92   1.42
#> 10 2010-01-10  0.394    0.117 0.278  1.33
#> # ... with 1,086 more rows
```

Comment: yes it can be determined dynamically using window - 1 as a variable.

Comment: Thanks! I have just one final question. Should the NA values be at the beginning of the `roll` column? That is, I start in `2010-01-30` and compute the RMSE for the past 30 days and would get my first RMSE result on `2010-01-30`, then we jump forward to `2010-02-01` and compute the RMSE values again obtaining a result for `2010-02-01`. Therefore all values `< 2010-01-30` would be NA. Adding in `arrange(desc(date)) %>%` should fix it? correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I think you want `rollmean(err, 30, align = "left", fill = NA)`.  If you want the NAs at the beginning use `rollmeanr` with an `r` at the end and omit `align=` .If you NAs at both ends (i.e. center alignment) just omit `align=`.

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this : you may consider putting the NA at the end as long as you interpret the `roll` column as "the moving rmse taken from here to the next window (30 here) values".

Comment: Good call @G.Grothendieck , using align = "left", "center" or "right" changes how you should interpret the `roll` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually with base R, i.e.

```
sapply(seq(0, (nrow(d) - 30)), function(i) Metrics::rmse(d$val1[(seq(30) + i)], d$val2[(seq(30) + i)]))
```